# How can I escape any of the special shell characters in a Python string?

Tags: python, bash, shell

How can I escape any of the special shell characters in a Python string?

The following characters need to be escaped:

```
$,!,#,&,",',(,),|,<,>,`,\,;
```

For example say I have this string:

```
str="The$!cat#&ran\"'up()a|<>tree`\;"
```

TIA

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this string just going to be used as a string (in which this isn't an issue), or passed to some shell command?

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't name variables `str`.  It will shadow the builtin `str` class.

Comment: Its passed to a shell script, I just used str here, the actual script has a different name.

Comment: edit queue is full?  wonder if they are all trying to move "TIA".  Also, the shlex answer should be accepted.  Even if OP was using Python2 in 2015, they shouldn't be now in 2021.

Answer (score 24):

In Python3, the required batteries are included as [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

> ```
> shlex.quote(s)
> ```
>
> Return a shell-escaped version of the string *`s`*. The returned value is a string that can safely be used as one token in a shell command line […].

In your example:

```
import shlex

s = "The$!cat#&ran\"'up()a|<>tree`\;"
print(shlex.quote(s))
```

Output:

```
'The$!cat#&ran"'"'"'up()a|<>tree`\;'
```

Comment: `shlex.quote ` is python3 only

Comment: The Python 2.7 equivalent is [`pipes.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote), which is the same as `shlex.quote` in Python 3.

Comment: @SamRoberts, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Actually, pipes.quote isn't escaping these 5 characters: ! $ ' " `
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`re.sub` will do the job:

```
re.sub("(!|\$|#|&|\"|\'|\(|\)|\||<|>|`|\\\|;)", r"\\\1", astr)
```

**Output**

```
The\$\!cat\#\&ran\"\'up\(\)a\|\<\>tree\`\\\;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to escape everything rather than quote as much as feasible, but, this should do it (replace `'@'` with another character not present in your string, if needed):

```
>>> escape_these = r'([$!#&"()|<>`\;' + "'])"
>>> print(re.sub(escape_these, r'@\1', s).replace('@','\\'))
The\$\!cat\#\&ran\"\'up\(\)a\|\<\>tree\`\\;
```

It may be doable with a tad less escape-trickery, but the unfortunate fact that strings, `re`, and the shell, all use the `\` (backslash) for escaping and other special purposes, does complicate things a bit:-).